# Объеденить части SQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно объеденить части SQL запроса, меня интересуют строки 3,4 и 13

```
$num = 6;

$page  = (int)$_GET['page'];

$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_products WHERE visible = '1'", 
$connect);

$temp  = mysql_fetch_array($count);

if ($temp[0] > 0) {

    $tempcount = $temp[0];

    $total = (($tempcount - 1) / $num) + 1;

    $total = intval($total);

    $page  = intval($page);

    if (empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;

    if ($page > $total) $page = $total;

    $start = $page * $num - $num;

    $qury_start_num = " LIMIT $start, $num";
}
```

Вот с этим запросом. И возможно ли такое вообще?

```
if ($filtering != '') {

    $query .= 'WHERE ' . $filtering . ' ORDER BY ' . $sorting;
} else {

    $query .= 'ORDER BY ' . $sorting;
}
```

Comment: Учитесь правильно и внятно писать вопрос. Пока то, что нужно понятно только вам

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, Вам необходимо, чтобы `visible = '1'` и `$filtering` в одном условии. Для этого необходимо использовать [SQL AND & OR Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp). В вашем случае это выглядело бы:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE visible = '1' AND ';
if ($filtering != '') {
    $query .= ' $filtering . ' ORDER BY ' . $sorting;
} else {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY ' . $sorting;
}
```

Опять же, если я правильно понял чего вы хотите:

p.s.:

- в 2016 году использовать функции "mysql" мягко говоря - не очень. Используйте "PDO" или "mysqli".